# Virtualhost: Put online a Flask website with Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

I try to put online a Flask website with Docker. So, I've created a Dockerfile, a docker-compose and now I can see my website online with my domain name.

Despite my Virtualhost, I can't access to my webiste by using subdomain and without port ":5000". This virtualhost seems to be totally ignored!

**Dockerfile:**

FROM python:latest

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi \
    build-essential \
    python \
    python-dev \
    python-pip \
    vim \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt-get autoremove

RUN apt-get install -y wget

COPY src /var/www/flask

RUN apt-get install -y python-requests
RUN pip install flask-user
RUN pip install -r var/www/flask/myapp/requirements.txt

COPY src/myapp/myapp.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod wsgi
RUN a2enmod proxy_http
RUN a2ensite myapp.conf
RUN service apache2 restart

EXPOSE 80
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
flask:
    image: flask:latest
    command: python /var/www/flask/myapp/__init__.py
    volumes:
    - "/root/workspace/python/src/:/var/www/flask"
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

**Virtualhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain.guru

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask/myapp/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/flask/myapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return "test" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

With these URL I can see my website:

- "*my.domain.guru:5000*"
- "*domain.guru:5000*" (why?)

But, I want to access to my website only with this URL : "*my.domain.guru*". If I try with this URL, I have the following error message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

How to do this?

(*I can't use the port 80 because it is already used by other websites*)

Comment: Does the forbidden also happen if you stop the container? I think that's happening because you have something else bound to Port 80

Comment: Not your problem but this line has not any sense because Apache is not running during build: "RUN service apache2 restart", you can remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is port 80: "my.domain.guru", So you need to configure the web server that currently runs at 80 to proxy you app in 5000.

Also, you are never running the Apache because your command runs only `__init__.py`. Don't think a container as a lightweight VM with is own service management. A container runs only the command/entrypoint that you define in Dockerfile or docker-compose.

So my recommendation is either to change your command to run Apache (`/usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND`) or point your current web server at port 80 to proxy the port 5000 of flask.